# TailwindCss classes not working in routes like /user/1

Tags: reactjs, routes, tailwind-css

i have configure tailwind css and its properly working when i give routes like /home ,/about
<Route path='/home' element={}>
<Route path='/about' element={}>

but when i make routes like /user/1
<Route path='/user/1' element={}>
then tailwind classes not working in that Route component in same project

Comment: did you ever get this working? I cant get it working for nested danymic urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clearly mentioned in tailwind docs. `./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}` path is available for tailwind, so try to see whether you path matches

**tailwind.config.js file**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

If not edit as per requirement.

Comment: my config file is just as above as mentioned in docs and it works on routes like /user but when routes chnage like /user/1 then its not working

Comment: Then for path `/user/1` modify it to `"./src/**/*/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Next 13 and there isn't a layout.tsx in the app folder, then make sure to import globals.css manually in other layout.jsx files. For instance a structure like the one below:

```
-app
  --(marketing)
    --layout.jsx
    --page.jsx
  --dashboard
    --layout.jsx
    --page.jsx
  --globals.css
  --favicon.ico
```